# Is there any special way to cook this specific kind of coffee from Indonesia?

Tags: ground-coffee, instant

I have this coffee which is from Indonesia with the following features:
Its taste and smell is totally different from the coffees that I have so far drunk in my life.
For example, it is totally different from Nescafé.
It looks like instant coffee, but I am not sure if it is.
It has a very impressive and touching scent.

Do you know what kind of coffee it is, and how to make it?

Comment: Do you have a brand name or anything to go off of? "Indonesian" coffee doesn't say much. Maybe a picture of it if not name?

Comment: What do you mean it looks like instant coffee? Do you mean it's a fine powder? And how would you describe the smell?

Comment: @RMac Yes it is powder but not supper thin. It has a very exotic smell for me. Recently I found out that its smell is kinda similar to the smell of Pepsi.

Comment: @NealC I have forgotten the name. I through away the bag.

Comment: I think either what you have isn't coffee or there is something very wrong with it. Coffee should always smell essentially like coffee unless it's a flavored coffee.